# How to customise the .deviceOwnerAuthentication view controller?

Tags: ios, swift3, biometrics, localauthentication

My latest app update was rejected due to the passcode view controller being too similar to that used by Apple.

But, I use the system provided view for the passcode. I don't know how to customise it. How do I do this?

Here is some code I use to choose this view to authenticate with..

```
var policy: LAPolicy?

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {

        policy = .deviceOwnerAuthentication

    } else {

        context.localizedFallbackTitle = "Fuu!"
        policy = .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics

    }
```

Also, this was the message I received from the App Store review team: "Your app contains features that mimic the iOS PIN Code.

￼Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please remove or revise these features to make them distinctly different from iOS behaviors and interfaces to avoid causing user confusion."

Answer (score 0):

Try using a customised view controller for more info see this lib on github
[A Touch ID and Passcode framework used in the Venmo app.](https://github.com/venmo/VENTouchLock)