# Why doesn't the LocalAuthentication offer both touchID and passcode?

Tags: swift, localauthentication

I want it so when I call this:

```
context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason) { (success, error) in
```

the UIAlertController that pops up offers an option to the user to select either TouchID or Passcode, and in the documentation I found that it's intended to do that, but for whatever reason it doesn't. Any idea of how I can get this to work?

Comment: When the Touch ID alert appears telling the user to authenticate using your finger, use the wrong finger and the alert changes to offer the passcode option.

Comment: I know that this is the normal flow @rmaddy, but I want it so that both options appear right away, rather than having to fail first.

Comment: That's not an option. File an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: where can I do that? @rmaddy

Comment: http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Hope the below link will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030483/how-to-customise-the-deviceownerauthentication-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030483/how-to-customise-the-deviceownerauthentication-view-controller)